Splunk search with wildcard in field name
I need to see all events with fields that have "PROD*" in name, e.g. "PROD deploy", "PROD update", etc.
index=myIndex sourcetype=mySourceType "PROD*"="*" doesn't work
..and if event has "PROD*" in field name I need to get the value
How is it possible?

You can use rex to extract field name and its value from "_raw".

Please provide some example data so we can reproduce your issue

With a rex: index=myIndex sourcetype=mySourceType PROD | rex "PROD (?<variable>[^=]+)=(?<value>.*)" | table variable value
